# DynamicLinks not working on first open React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, dynamic-linking, firebase-dynamic-links, react-native-linking

I have my project in `React Native (v0.62.2)`, and I am using `Firebase Dynamic Links (v^12.0.0)`. I have configured it all as the documentation indicates, but I have a problem:

In iOS, if I use an external dynamic link (such as `https://myapp.page.link/ref_TEST`) works only if the app is previously downloaded from AppStore. Otherwise, if the app is not downloaded, this link will redirect me to AppStore to download it. But when I open the app after download, I will lose the dynamic link.

Does anyone have a clue about this? I searched a lot, and there are people having this problem but didn't found a solution to it.

Thanks!

Comment: [UPDATE]: I resolved this by getting the dynamic link in a deeper component. So when app first renders, the DL does not come. But when I navigate between components or screens, this DL appears

Comment: What did you mean by DL? I have the same problem. I have added an alert for the getInitialLink() code in my App.js file but when I download the app using a dynamic link but I didn’t get the value of that link.

Comment: DL: Dynamic Link.

Do you want to provide me any example? Maybe I can help

Comment: I have messaged you on Instagram can you please check it